# I can't update or remove java 10.67.2 plugin in firefox 47.0

Tags: 14.04, firefox, java

When I click on (plugin) update now it is blocked and I am re-directed to the update now button to update Java.

I updated Java to version 8 update 91. I followed the instructions about removing the link to the old plugin and updated the link in `~mozzilla/plugins` to point at the new plugin. I restarted Firefox (rebooted also). Still no luck.

I removed packages jre and jdk so I had only java 8 running. Same issue... I cannot remove or update the plugin in Firefox.

```
todd@todd-GX270:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

todd@todd-GX270:~/.mozilla/plugins$ ls -alc
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 todd todd 4096 Jun 12 14:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 todd todd 4096 Jun  8 21:31 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 todd todd   51 Jun 12 14:39 libnpjp2.so -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
```

Should I remove Oracle Java 8 and go back to JRE or JDK that was previously installed (part of Ubuntu I think)?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Java Plugin within Firefox itself doesn't work in Linux, you have to [downlad](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) the latest Oracle JDK or JRE and link to the new Plugin as described below.

Close Firefox and open the Terminal:

```
cd .mozilla/plugins   
sudo rm -rf libnpjp2.so 
ln -s /path-to-jdk-or-jre-firefox-plugin/libnpjp2.so .
```

Replace 'path-to-jdk-or-jre-firefox-plugin' with the real path to your *latest* jdk or jre on your computer. Don't forget the '.' at the end of the above line!

Start Firefox and chek in 'about:plugins' or 'Tools → Add-ons'

This should work, if the path to the plugin is correct...

Comment: Hi Neni - I was pretty sure that this was exactly what I did. I redid exactly what you said and I still have the problem.<p> When I look at about:plugins it has <p> Java(TM) Plug-in 10.67.2

    File: libnpjp2.so
    Path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
    Version: 10.67.2
    State: Enabled (STATE_VULNERABLE_UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
    Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.67.2 for Mozilla browsers <p>

Comment: I thought I had only 1 version of java.   java -version shows todd@todd-GX270:~/.mozilla/plugins$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14).... could that be where that plugin is coming from?
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)  If I look at /usr/lib/jvm I see    todd@todd-GX270:~/.mozilla/plugins$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
java-6-sun  java-6-sun-1.6.0.26  java-8-oracle

Comment: hmm, your plugin is pretty old... I would suggest you to download the latest jdk or jre (link is in the answer) manually and do the link with this new folder... if it works, do the other procedures (update-alternatives...) with this folder and delete all the others...

Comment: I did all that already. I will get rid of the sun javas. They may be interefering.

Comment: I lost again. I removed Sun java 6 and now only have the following installed.

Comment: I am lost again. I have removed Sun Java 6 in case it was conflicting and am running only the latest Java 8.    java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

When I start Firefox and look at about:plugins  it says that my plugin version
is Java(TM) Plug-in 10.67.2   File: libnpjp2.so
Path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
Version: 10.67.2
State: Enabled (STATE_VULNERABLE_UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.67.2 for Mozilla browsers

Comment: When I look at pluguns it is still disabled and says vulnerable. get the latest. I have the correct link in .mozzilla plugins 
libnpjp2.so -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre//lib/i386/libnpjp2.

I found a page to remove this Java version and i see it also shows a link to 
iremove the plugin there 
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    51 Jun  8 21:19 mozilla-javaplugin.so -> 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
The plugins both point to the same file and they are the latest???
Does this mean that 10.67.2 is the latest and is block and vulnerable? or is something else still screwy?